# What import do I need to avoid "java: package util does not exist." in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Java and even newer to Intellij. I am building a project and I have one module called BigCalc. In that module I have two subdirectories, src and tests. I am using the src directory to house 3 more directories: bigcalc, javadoc, and util.

- bigcalc contains classes such as add, multiply as well as a main calculator program.
- javadoc contains javadocs
- util contains utilities like List, Queue, Stack,etc...

In the tests directory I have my Junit tests in two subdirectories: bigcalctests and utiltests.

I want to run the Junit tests, but the compiler throws an error message when compiling the tests in bigcalctests. The error reads:

> java: package util does not exist.

In all of src>util>"classes"  I have written "package util;"
And in all bigcalctests I have written `import util.*`. I even tried `import src.util.*;`.

Comment: You import classes, not packages. Have you tried `import BigCalc.src.util.List;`?

Comment: I tried it. Same error. It says it does not exist. Perhaps it has something to do with my configuration. This is my working directory C:\Users\Selvin\Documents\Assignments\CISC187\BigCalc\tests

Comment: Did you create `src` or was it created for you?

Comment: I created src and tests

Comment: When I create a new IntelliJ project, a new directory called `src` is created for me. If I put a packages called `X` and `Y` in `src`, the import statements do not begin with `src`. E.g. from a class within `Y` I do `import X.MyClass;`.

Comment: You are right. I had created two modules. One was src, the other was tests. I now inserted tests into the src directory. It is compiling now. Thanks

Comment: You should not have `src` as part of your package name.